# How to Zip files(i.e *.t00 or *.rf0 extn) which are older than 7 days by using pkzipc command?

Tags: batch-file, archive

How to Zip files(i.e *.t00 or *.rf0 extn) which are older than 7 days by using `pkzipc` command in dos batch file and name today's date and time to zip file name, and later move that zip file to Archive directory ?

Comment: You might be interested in `forfiles /D -7` -- see `forfiles /?`...

Answer (score 0):

PKZip has extension filters and the "before" parameter that you can use to limit it to files older than a specific date.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems before option is working only if we provide date format(i.e  DDMMYYYY ) in command line and might not work for our requirement where we can only give parameter value as number of days (i.e. 7 days), is there any way to handle days to consider for pkzip command.

Answer (score 0):

After some hit & trial, reached this script which solved my problem for zipping files older than 7 days, (I set path and date formulae in the start of command file)

```
forfiles -p "%ZipPath%\Input" -m *.* -d -7 -c "cmd /c %ZipPath%\CMD\pkzipc -add %ZipPath%\Output\Zipped_%mydate%.zip  @path"
```

Thanks to everyone for helping me to find out solution.